# Creating slope map from DEM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, slope

I'm working on a student project trying to make a slope map with degree values. I downloaded a DEM file from a map service and used the raster ->analyze(tool)->terrain model and got the model. Now I would like to make a slope map

I googled it and found [Calculating slope in percentage with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100206/calculating-slope-in-percentage-with-qgis)

The second answer seem to have the solution, but I'm simply too much of a beginner to quite get what I have to click, step by step, to do this. He links to [gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html)

How do I make the operation to get the percent slope values?

Comment: Are you looking for slope in percentages or slope in degrees? There is a slight difference between the two.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS (build 2.16.2) there is a function for this build in, as is the case in many GIS programs, which calculates the slope for you.

In QGIS this tool can be found under 'Raster'-> 'Terrain Analysis' -> 'Slope', in the menu bar at the top.

As input it requires your DEM raster file.