# How to reclassify to make sense of the percent slope map

Tags: qgis, legend, slope

I managed to make my slope map for a school project, in what is supposed to be percent, but how do I make the values make any sense? I need a legend where I classify the different values in 0-5%, 5-10%, 10-20% and 20-30% and 30 and above % and give those values different colors.

[image]

This is what I've done so far:

In my [first thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218272/creating-slope-map-from-dem-using-qgis) I was told I have to reclassify my slope map and was linked here:

[How to reclass a raster with reclassify grid values in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis/121559#121559)

I tried follow this but I really didn't get far. When using the values he did my map just got black, with some small with dots.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Remember that percentages are hundredths, so you may have a unit conversion issue.  Look at the raster statistics to verify units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download plugin named **Slicer**. It's very easy to use.

Select input image, set output filename, select `Variable` and add initial and end value, click `add` to aggregate interval as a class, then finish with `Slice` button.

[image]

After executing the process, go to `Properties`(right click on your output raster in Layers panel) and go to `Style` and select `Singleband pseudocolor`, you can check the steps to apply a color palette in [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html).

The result could be something like this (DEM from a very mountainous area):

[image: dem]

**PS:** Don't forget to set legend values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 

I have some more questions; In the Slicer-plugin the maximum value was set to 4,9 after executing "slice", I suppose I have to convert some values?

This is how things looked after I used Slice;
[Image 1](http://imgur.com/YWSIvhS) 

And this is how things looked after I tried adding the values;

[Image 2](http://imgur.com/YWSIvhS)

Comment: Don't worry, follow the link that I put in my answer to apply colors in your classification. In your case color black /gray goes from 1 up to 4, 5 is white. Use information tool to evaluate pixels in white areas and check what I said.

Comment: Thank you again, I really aprecciate the help. 

So, now my problem is that even though I choose the low areas to be purple, and the higher ones to be green, the map just looks all purple. 

[Image](http://imgur.com/EkEY0GS)

What am I doing wrong this time? Clearly I'm really overlooking something obvious it feels like.

Comment: Did you look raster values? Clases from Slicer has integer consecutive values. Class number 1 (0-10%) has value of 1, class number 2 (10-20%) has value of 2, and so on. So, you need to set colors by integer number, and in `label` write the class description (i.e: 0-10%)

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Does this look correct to you?

[Image](http://imgur.com/L3AsEIw)

Thank you again for taking the time to answer.