# Extracting data from ASCII file?

Tags: qgis, raster, r, altitude

I have ASCII files for a country that map altitude. I'd like to extract information on slopes for specific cities in my country. My goal is to have at least a rough idea of physical constraints in those cities. I thought about using the variance of altitude within each city. I have them in vectorial format.

I have no idea of how to do that. I can use QGIS or R.

EDIT : I successfully created a slope map. My problem now is how to cut my slope map using the polygons for cities, and then compute an average slope value within each city

EDIT 2: I found the solution on the internet, with the Zonal statistics plug-in

Comment: "ASCII" is not a good description of a file format, its an encoding of characters from binary numbers. An ASCII-encoded file is one that generally presents as plain text. Some geospatial data formats use ASCII-coded plain text - for example the format known as "ESRI ASCII GRID".  Do you have one of these? Or is it a comma-separated value file with lines like "2.3, 4.3, 897.34"?

Comment: I have never delt with this kind of data. When I tried opening it, it opened with QGIS. It looks like this when I open it with textedit : 

ncols        1000
nrows        1000
xllcorner    74962.500000000000
yllcorner    6750037.500000000000
cellsize     75.000000000000
NODATA_value  -99999.00
 -99999.00 -99999.00 -99999.00 -99999.00 -99999.00 -99999.00 -99999.00

Comment: Now you've worked out how to open it you should create a new question for any other problems you have. Judging by your edits you've solved your problems and now this question is a bit of a hodgepodge of questions and answers, so probably not much use to anyone else so probably worth deleting.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to import the ASCII file as points, then interpolate a DEM. A quick google search will return many explanations. For example, See:
[this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118243/create-a-dem-from-point-data) to [Creating DEM from Point Data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/118243/115)

Then create a slope raster from the DEM. Again, google it. i.e.: [Creating slope map from DEM using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218272)